# Daily Report Email Generated by Query

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a formula in a sheet as follows:

```
=QUERY(
   IMPORTRANGE(
    "1ZKw8d7OKX_LqnYx_84IHP2fuBo-6rzzZ7TuaQOfCjio","Data!A2:D7"
   ), 
   "select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 where Col4 != 'Completed' ", 
   0
 )
```

This working formula shows me all items pulled from another sheet that is not marked "Completed" of course.  I'd like to be able to take whatever shows up in this query/importrange and send an email each morning around 5 AM.  Is this a simple task?  Seems simple in theory.  Thank you for helping.

Comment: Askers should show what did they tried. See [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest the following steps :

Use `getRange().getValues()` to receive your data from the sheet cells

Organize this in HTML format

Use class [MailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app) to send the e-mail

Use [Google Apps trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) to send this e-mail every morning

Comment: Thank you Eugene.  Sorry for the delayed reply.